# Is a compound sharding key made of timestamp + search filed a good one?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, horizontal-scaling

A collection of events where `province` has a low cardinality and `start_date` is the timestamp:

```
{
    name: 'Party',
    province: 'Rome',
    start_date: 1369762458
}
```

I know that an **ascending key** as sharding key is not a good choice, ending up with an hotspot (all writes go to the last shard). A **low cardinality** is again a bad choice, as we'll end up with unsplittable chunks.

So, the compound key made of `start_date` + `province` is a good choice? Why in this case the don't have an hotspot?

Comment: If your queries use the `province` and `start_date` field it will work. There are many queries which MUST have the entire shard key to work otherwise there is simply no way of knowing which exact shard it should go to. As for hot spots, it is because the shard key is now compounded between both province and start date allowing for decent balancing and so no real hot spots

Comment: Yes, i would query a lot for events in a given province, ordering maybe by date. However I can't get how the compound key makes the hotspots impossible to happen. Any help?

Comment: See my answer - you can still get hotspots within each province but if your data represents multiple provinces, then you will be mitigating it by splitting the inserts among multiple chunks (by province) but avoiding low cardinality unsplittable chunks by having a compound shard key.

Answer (score 3):

Using start_date, province would be bad as the first part of the shard key would be monotonically ascending.  However, using province, start_date might be better and the "hotspot" problem would be *reduced* (though possibly not eliminated).

If you have a massive number of writes coming in at once as long as they represent multiple different provinces they will be directed to different chunks.  If a single province has a disproportional number of writes then you could end up with a hotspot (or hot chunk) however, as long as you have a reasonable distribution of your writes across multiple provinces (and as long as you have a reasonably high number of provinces rather than, say, two or three!) you will end up distributing the "hot spot" as well.

Comment: I have thought of one thing though, I must admit I am not knowledged on how a compound shard key is formed in the background, but if it is anything like a compound index wouldn't using province first cause a low cardinality problem (as stated in his question) due to its precendance?

Comment: of course not - cardinality refers to the entire shard key - your cardinality is how many different distinct values the shard key can have.

Comment: So within the sharding cluster a compound of `province` and `start_date` would mean there can be more shards than `province` values? So that the key is used like so `{province:'rome',start_date:123}` and not `{province:rome}` and then `{start_date:123}`

Comment: Just look at sh.status() output. Chunk ranges go from {province:val, paymentID:val} to {province:val, paymentID:val2} compound key means compound value.  A single province can be represented by multiple chunks IFF it had more payments than could fit in a single chunk.

Comment: and I assume you mean "more chunks than province values" and the answer to that is of course "yes"

Comment: Assuming the compound shard key? If it was only province as the shard key it would be different right? But yea since I know it is a compound value that forms the shard key and not some other method I can explain that now, thanks#